# Disconnected : No supported authentication methods available (server sent :publickey) on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redhat

I created an `instance` of Linux on Amazon EC2. I try to configure it but I have a connection problem. I'm using a `Key Pair` that other `instance` have and I don't believe the problem is for that.

```
Disconnected : No supported authentication methods available (server sent:publickey)
```

I'm used the user `ec2-user` and I was creating the `Private Key` from the *.pem file.

I saw some question here and other place, and I try to resolve for other methods but the problem don't work.

Psdt: Can be because I have a instance in termination?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the key pair that you specified during Instances creation? You can see what key you are using for your instance using the consol. Simply click on the instance to view details and check the 'Key pair name'. Also, can you verify that the contents of your key file starts with '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----' and end with '-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'

Comment: Yes, I verify. I have the key with the same name in my computer but the error still happening. I'm gonna create a new instance because I have been try a lot of things.

Comment: Can you post the output of `ssh -v ......`?

Comment: You can see the output here.

https://i.imgur.com/UjLdRg6.png

Comment: What is the status of the instance you're trying to connect to?

Comment: How did you generate the PPK file for Putty ?